# AttributeError in sklearn_crfsuite has no attribute CRF arror

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, attributeerror, spacy, rasa-nlu

I am getting this error when trying our rasa_nlu with spacy

> AttributeError: 'sklearn_crfsuite' object has no attribute 'CRF'

**rasa_nlu** was importing this way
`import sklearn_crfsuite`

So I tried importing like below before calling **rasa_nlu**
`from sklearn_crfsuite import CRF`

But getting a different

> error - cannot import name 'CRF'

Looking for some suggestions.

Comment: Show the full stack trace of error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `sklearn_crfsuite.CRF`, then do `import sklearn_crfsuite` to import it. If you're importing with `from sklearn_crfsuite import CRF`, then just use `CRF` by itself.

Comment: import sklearn_crfsuit is what is there already within rasa_nlu. when i followed the error. So thats why I tried rom sklearn_crfsuit import CRF.

Comment: @Dexters You also appear to be missing the "e" on the end of the name. It's "suite", not "suit".

Comment: Thanks for catching this. Sorry, Its a question typo. I made a mistake when I tried to recreate the error for the question. But Original error remains.